# Regarding a property of Klein modular function J

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-function

I am self studying analytic number theory and I could not deduce this statement given in Tom M Apostol.

Statement is - The function J takes every value exactly once in closure of fundamental region.

Two theorems have been proved earlier, both of whose proofs I understood completely ( They are very easy) . 
Theorem 1- If f is modular and not constant then f - c  has same no. of zeroes and poles in closure of fundamental region where c is any constant belonging to $ C $ . In other words, f takes all values equally often in closure of fundamental region.

Theorem 2 - If f is modular and bounded then it is constant.

Now, deduction of statement to be proved - Using theorem 1 and 2 I can deduce that J takes all values equally oftenly as it is modular.

But can someone please explain how to prove that J takes all values  exactly once.

Comment: $J$ has only one pole at $i\infty$, and it is a simple pole (in the chart around $i\infty$ that we use to define the completed modular curve as a Riemann surface), you need it in my previous answer to find a polynomial in $J(t)$ cancelling the pole of $g(t)$ at $i\infty$

Comment: @reuns  can you please explain a bit more how the property J has only simple pole at i \infty implies J takes each value exactly once. I am sorry but i can't deduce it.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 2.5 is "Apply the previous theorem to $\,f-c\,$.What is a zero or pole of $\,f-c?\,$

Comment: @Somos  got it now